# The default value with or without "()" in a Django model field and "ValueError: Cannot serialize function" error

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-models, default

### <The 1st case>:

I can use [timezone.now()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/utils/#django.utils.timezone.now) with or without `()` as a default value in [DateTimeField()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#datetimefield) as shown below:

```py
from django.utils import timezone
                                               # Here
datetime = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())
```

Or:

```py
from django.utils import timezone
                                               # Here
datetime = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

So, what is the difference between `now()` and `now`?

### <The 2nd case>:

I can use `timezone.now().date()` with `()` as a default value in [DateField()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#datefield) as shown below:

```py
from django.utils import timezone
                                             # Here
date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now().date())
```

Also, I can use `timezone.now().date` without `()` as a default value in `DateField()` as shown below but when running `python manage.py makemigrations`:

```py
from django.utils import timezone
                                             # Here
date = models.DateField(default=timezone.now().date)
```

Then, I got the error below:

> ValueError: Cannot serialize function <built-in method date of datetime.datetime object at 0x0000019D077B70F0>: No module

So, what is the difference between `now().date()` and `now().date`?

Lastly overall, which should I use, the default value with or without `()` in a Django model field?

Answer (score 0):

The difference is WHEN the function is going to be executed. Django loads class' attributes during initialising whole application. Let's say you start hosting your application 29.05.2023 at 13:00.

Now everytime you will create on object with some `DateTimeField` with default value of `timezone.now()`, then you will have always the same value of 29.05.2023 at 13:00, even if object is created on the next day.

If you pass it without brackets, then you pass function itself and function will be called exactly in the moment of creation, so it will return exact date and time of an object creation.

For the second case you might need to create seperate function, I think because of the first function (`now()` just before `date`) that is called during project initialization. Example:

```py
from django.utils import timezone

def today():
    return timezone.now().date

date = models.DateField(default=today)
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple visual difference is timezone.now() function will generate new migration files everytime whenever you run makemigrations command but timezone.now will generate only once.